# Cannot login in Joomla

Tags: authentication, joomla, joomla1.5

I'm having some trouble getting a Joomla 1.5 installation to work on my computer.

When I login, it seems to work as JApplication::login() returns true. Also when I debug and var_dump the response, I can see the user.

However, when I reload the page, I'm still not logged in so it seems Joomla didn't save the current session.

I've looked in the framework and can't find how sessions are saved. Also the log is empty.

Does anybody know what could be the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have the same problem in the administrator and in the frontend? If you do have access to your administrator, it might be a frontend problem. You can check the file "configuration.php" in your joomla root, and look for this line:

```
var $session_handler = 'database';
```

If it's empty, it means you've had some problem saving your configuration. The usual values for "session_handler" are 'database' or 'file', and you might have some others depending on your setup.
If your session_handler is ok, then check this value too:

```
var $lifetime = '15';
```

It's the session lifetime if I'm not wrong.
If you're still having problems, you should check in a separate script (not Joomla) if you can use sessions, just to make sure you haven't problems with your local set up.

I hope it helped!